# How to catch error if .env file not found in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, svelte

Let's say I import an .env variable using

`import { PUBLIC_URL } from '$env/static/public';`

If the variable does not exists, it will throw an `HTTP 500 Internal Server error` and I can read the error in the console.

Now if someone else clones the repository and does not have an `.env` file, I would like to catch this error message and throw a decent error description.

How can I achieve this?

I tried using `fs.exists()`, but it seems that I am unable to use `fs` in Svelte. I also tried importing `dotenv` and running config. It gives an error `process is not defined`, when the file does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `+page.server.ts` you can check for the presence of `PUBLIC_URL` and if it doesn't exist, redirect to an error page to display your desired message.

```
import { PUBLIC_URL } from "$env/static/public";
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export const load = async () => {
    if (!PUBLIC_URL) {
        throw redirect(303, "/no-env");
    }

    return {};
};
```

This works because the page server load function (`+page.server.ts`) will run before the client-side presentation layer (`+page.svelte.ts`).

Just make sure that the page you redirect to doesn't also require `PUBLIC_URL`, or else you'll face the same 500 error.